# Iframe with same width and height as div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a `<div>` with some styles. Some of them are:

```
contenedor.style.position = "absolute";
contenedor.style.top = "60px";
contenedor.style.left = "610px";
contenedor.style.width = "auto"; // Auto-adjust to the content
contenedor.style.height = "auto";// Auto-adjust to the content
```

Then, I've created an `<iframe>`:

```
iframe.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
iframe.style.width = contenedor.style.width;
iframe.style.height = contenedor.style.height;
iframe.style.top = contenedor.style.top;
iframe.style.left = contenedor.style.left;
```

But, when I show both elements, the `<iframe>` is bigger than the `<div>`. It has not the same width and height as the `<div>`. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: could it be to do with padding / border ? have you tried setting these to 0?

Comment: Use the developer tools of your browser to see the dimensions in which they're being rendered

Comment: Just a strange question: what's the point of the `div`?  It has width and height set to `auto` anyway, so why not get rid of it altogether and just use iframe on its own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try making the width and height of the iframe 100%?

Comment: Have you tried using 100% width and height on the div as well as the iframe?

Comment: Can you post the link to where you are trying to implement this.

Comment: Can you at least put it somewhere where we can see it.

Comment: Now, I've got this code

iframe.style.width = contenedor.clientWidth;
 iframe.style.height = contenedor.clientHeight;

Problem is that clientHeight only are active while div is active, so they're always 0. But they are the sizes that body asign them, and the sizes that I want for my iframe... please help me :(